# Set true/false Properties of Objects in JavaScript 2D Array

Tags: javascript

I have a 2D array that is full of literal objects. The objects have properties that are either `true` or `false`. My problem:

I have tried setting the the properties in this fashion

```
SpacesObjectsArray[2][0].HasRotator = true;
```

This however, will set every `.HasRotator` property in the array to true not just the one located at `[2][0]`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you constructing the array?  Could you post a code snippet, please?

Comment: Seems to me that every element of the array references **the same** object. How are you creating the array?

Comment: "References the same object" This sounds like what I'm doing wrong. I'm going to mess with this and get back to ya. Thank ya!

Answer (score 1):

I coded it up just to show you that it works if you create your arrays properly: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3uxcr/.  Therfore, there must be a problem with the way you are creating the two dimensional array because if it is created properly, the line of code you have works.

As others have said, you may have an array of references to all the same object and thus when you change that object, all the references see the change to the same object.

Comment: Yup thats what I was doing. I was just sticking the same object in the array over and over. Thanks alot jfriend00 and Felix Kling